# Search an Input and get output related to input Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an input box that asks for a student name, and when someone types a certain name, html will print to the screen displaying that certain student's statistics. I am have trouble with this especially since the console doesn't say there are any errors.

Here is my code that does absolutely nothing as of now.

Also, I don't want any prompts, alerts, or anything like that, I want it to purely be on the page.

Basically, I want it to be a search box for a student's name, and then outputs their stats. So when you click the button, and the student's name you entered matches one in the code, the html will display that student's stats.

________________ 
  |STUDENT_NAME_| <=== student name search here. **BUTTON**

Then output these stats: 
              track: 'Front End Development', 
              achievements: '158',
              points: '14730'

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

  First name: <input id="first_name">
<button onclick="getStudentReport" id="output"></button>

  <hr>
  <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
    var students = [
      {
        name: 'Hanna',
          track: 'Front End Development',
            achievements: '158',
              points: '14730'
      },
      {
        name: 'Joshua',
          track: 'iOS Development with Swift',
            achievements: '175',
              points: '16375'
      },
      {
        name: 'Becky',
          track: 'PHP Development',
            achievements: '55',
              points: '2025'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jacob',
          track: 'Learn WordPress',
            achievements: '40',
              points: '1950'
      },
      {
        name: 'Dug',
          track: 'Rails Development',
            achievements: '5',
              points: '350'
      }
    ];

    function print(message) {
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
    }

    function getStudentReport(student) {
      var report = '<h2>Student: ' + student.name + '</h2>';
      report += '<p>Track: ' + student.track + '</p>';
      report += '<p>Points: ' + student.points + '</p>';
      report += '<p>Achievements: ' + student.achievements + '</p>';
      return report;
    }

    function say_hi() {
      var student = document.getElementById('first_name').value;

      if (student.name === students) {
        message = getStudentReport(student);
        print(message);
      }

      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
    }

    document.getElementById('output').addEventListener('click', 
    getStudentReport);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit. please check this [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7jnd7L2o/)

To summarise I see few issues. You function `getStudentReport` expects a `student` object but you are not passing it anywhere when calling it on click of button. I modified that line as below

```
getStudentReport(getStudent())
```

where `getStudent` is a new function as shown below

```
function getStudent() {
    var student = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    if (student != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            if (students[i].name.toLowerCase() === student.toLowerCase()) {
                return students[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Also there is no need to add a listener using `addEventListener` if you are adding `onclick` on button. So I removed that line. Also there is no code to print the report so I modified the `onclick` of button as below

```
onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = getStudentReport(getStudent())"
```

Overall the final HTML is not the best way to achieve what you are trying to accomplish but I leave the refactoring to you

Comment: still not working for me, suppose I'll just have to copy some code online and modify it....

Comment: did you try the JSFiddle link I gave? You can type Joshua or Becky or any other name and result is getting printed just below the input box

Comment: how do I add the the enter button, so that the user can have the option of pressing enter? I tried to add it to my code but I'm not sure where exactly to add it.

Comment: there are couple of options, either you can handle `keypress` event on your button and check for enter keycode or you can wrap your `input` and `button` inside a form. On press of enter it will trigger a `submit` event on form

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle to handle enter keypress

Comment: I dont see the enter code? and when I press enter nothing happens :/

Comment: Oh, I see, I have to tab over to the button (at least that's the only thing working for me right now). Is there a way to trigger it instantly rather than having to tab over to the button?

Comment: check the JSFiddle.I have changed the code. You dont need to tab over button.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below. On input change you output a list of names which match the input string and then click one to show your report. Its a better pattern because you can select between duplicates.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var matches = document.getElementById('matches');
    var input = document.getElementById('first_name');
    var result = document.getElementById('result');

    matches.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        var studentID = event.target.dataset.studentid;
        var record = students[studentID];
        result.innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${record.name}</br> Track: ${record.track} Achievements: ${record.achievements} Points: ${record.points}</div>`
    })

input.addEventListener('input', function(event){
    matches.innerHTML = '';
    var matchArr = [];
    var inputString = event.target.value;
    for(var i in students){
        var student = students[i];
        if(student.name.substring(0, inputString.length).toLowerCase() == inputString.toLowerCase() && inputString.length > 0){
        matchArr.push(i);
            }
        }
        displayStudents(matchArr);
    });
})

function displayStudents(matchArr){
   for(var i in matchArr){
       var studentID = matchArr[i];
       var e = document.createElement('div');
       e.dataset.studentid = studentID;
       e.innerHTML = students[studentID].name;
       matches.appendChild(e);
   }
}

First name: <input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name">
<div id="matches"></div>
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
```

[Example](https://jsbin.com/kipabokoba/edit?html,css,js,console,output)